# paused SKScene continues when unlocking iPhone

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene

I used `self.scene.view.paused = YES;`to pause my scene.

When i pause the game everything is fine. A pauseMenu appears and everything is paused.

But when I press pause and lock the phone and unlock it again the pauseMenu is still active like it should be but the game itself is not paused anymore.

Is there a function i should use for a specific scene that gets called when you enter the app again when the phone was locked?

This does not happen when you just tap the home button and then reentering the app.

Comment: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification - An app is active when it is receiving events. An active app can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains focus when the device is unlocked. Utilize - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application